# program that ask consecutive math questions

Tags: python

I need to make a program that asks you to answer a series of math questions. I'm able to make it ask random operations and the numbers for the operation, but I want to make it ask numerous questions in one run. I think I need to make a loop, but I don't know how to do that. I basically want it to ask as many questions until the user stops, and I want it to count the score, and how many attempts were made. It's in French, so bear with me.

```
#-Importation des modules
import random


#Define operations
Operation = ("Addition", "Soustraction", "Multiplication", "Division", "Exposant", "Pente", "Point de Millieu")
Question = random.choice(Operation) #Chose random operation
score = 0 #Everytime you get a right answer, add a point
#Les questions

#Addition
if Question == "Addition":
    num1 = random.randint(10,100)
    num2 = random.randint(50,200)
    BnReponse = num1 + num2 #Right answer
    print(f"Trouve la somme de {num1}+{num2}")
    ReponseUs = int(input(f"C'est quoi la somme de {num1}+{num2} est: ")) #User's answer
    if ReponseUs == BnReponse:
        print("Correct")
        score+=1
        print(f"Le score est: {score}")
    else:
        print(f"Incorrect, la reponse est {BnReponse}")

#Soustraction
elif Question == "Soustraction":
    num1 = random.randint(100,200)
    num2 = random.randint(10,80)
    BnReponse = num1 - num2 #La bonne reponse
    print(f"Trouve la difference de {num1}-{num2}")
    ReponseUs = int(input(f"C'est quoi la difference de {num1}-{num2} est: "))
    if ReponseUs == BnReponse:
        print("Correct")
        score+=1
    else:
        print(f"Incorrect, la reponse est {BnReponse}")

#Multiplication
elif Question == "Multiplication":
    num1 = random.randint(10,20)
    num2 = random.randint(10,20)
    BnReponse = num1 * num2 #La bonne reponse
    print(f"Trouve le quotient de {num1}*{num2}")
    ReponseUs = int(input(f"C'est quoi le quotient de {num1}-{num2} est: "))
    if ReponseUs == BnReponse:
        print("Correct")
        score+=1
    else:
        print(f"Incorrect, la reponse est {BnReponse}")
```

Comment: Consider doing some research on a `while` loop, as this will continue infinitely, until a condition is met.

Comment: @diggusbickus oops

Answer (score 0):

For the loop, you can do something like this if you want an infinite loop:

```
while True:
    ...
```

or if you want a numerous loop (10 times for the example):

```
for i in range(10):
    ...
```

for this, i equal the number of the question (i=0 for the first, i=1 for the second...).
To stop the loop, you can also use `break` in your code like this:

```
while True:
    question = input('')
    if question == 'stop':
        break
```

And to count the scores, just do

```
score += 1
```

each time the player wins, and print it at the end :)

Answer (score 0):

> I'm able to make it ask random operations and the numbers for the operation, but I want to make it ask numerous questions in one run. I think I need to make a loop, but I don't know how to do that.

Depends on what kind of behavior you want for the loop but the one that jumps out to me for your case is a while loop. You can make a variable and set it to true and then when the user decides to stop then set that variable to false. And you can count the number of iterations with a counter variable.

```
counter_var = 0
loop_var = True    
while loop_var:
    counter_var += 1
    # your code to ask questions goes in here
```

At the end of the loop you can ask the user whether or not they want to continue with `input` and based on that set `loop_var` to false.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add a loop so it would look a bit like:

```
#-Importation des modules

import random

#Define operations
score = 0 #Everytime you get a right answer, add a point
Operation = ("Addition", "Soustraction", "Multiplication", "Division", "Exposant", "Pente", "Point de Millieu")
game = True
turns =0
#Les questions
while game:
    turns ++
    Question = random.choice(Operation) #Chose random operation
    #Here you would insert your game code
    if (input("Do you want to stop playing Y/N") == "Y"): #detecting if they said Y
         game = False
         print("You scored: " + score + " after: " + turns + " attempts")
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to give the solution away as it is for a homework assignment but hopefully, this will be a good start to help with your issue.

I just added a while loop to your code and showed a possible way you could exit the loop using the `wantQuestion` boolean and asking the user if they want another question after every question.

```
#Importation des modules
import random

#Define operations
Operation = ("Addition", "Soustraction", "Multiplication") #Add more operations
score = 0 #Everytime you get a right answer, add a point
wantQuestion = True #True means the user wants another question

while (wantQuestion): #runs while wantQuestion is True
    Question = random.choice(Operation) #Chose random operation
    #Les questions
    if Question == "Addition":
        print("Addition Code runs")
    elif Question == "Soustraction":
        print("Soustraction Code runs")
    elif Question == "Multiplication":
        print("Multiplication Code runs")
    # Other operations

    keyboardInput = input("Would you like another question (Y/n): ")
    if (keyboardInput == "y" or keyboardInput == "Y"):
        wantQuestion = True
    else:
        wantQuestion = False

print("Display what you want after you've stopped asking questions")
```

Comment: I did that, but for some reason, the code only repeats the same type operation

Comment: Add you made sure to put the line `Question = random.choice(Operation)` inside the while-loop right? That will make sure, every time it loops, it will pick a new question.